# Displaying validation errors on "new" view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this [section](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-some-validation) of the Rails guide, it is instructed to add `@article = Article.new` in the `new` method of `ArticlesController`, explaining that otherwise we won't be able to access `@article.errors`.

From what I understand, `@articles = Article.new` creates a new instance of `Article`, and what we need is the `@article` variable that we tried to submit. I know it works but I need to understand why.

Controller code:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end

end
```

View code:

```
<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id='error_explanation'>
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this articles from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It says this:

> The reason why we added @article = Article.new in the
>   ArticlesController is that otherwise @article would be nil in our
>   view, and calling @article.errors.any? would throw an error.

so it has nothing to do with accessing validation errors.

Without the `@article` variable in `new` action you would call `errors` method in your view on `nil` value and `nil` doesn't have such a method, so you would get an error `undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass`. In case of `@article` variable set to `Article.new` you call `errors` method on an `Article` class instance and since there are no validation errors (yet) the `#error_explanation` block will not be rendered.

But when you try to create a new record, then validation occurs. And if there are validation errors your rails app renders the `new` template again, but it does it with the `create` action. Therefore, the `@article` variable this time is the one from the `create` method and since we have validation errors in it, the `#error_explanation` block will be rendered and user will see what's wrong.